# Robot Framework Teardown not executed if Jenkins job aborted

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm running Robot Framework tests using Jenkins.
My suite has a setup and teardown steps, which are mandatory! The problem is that when Jenkins aborts the build during the running test, my teardown step is not being executed. How it possible to execute the Robot Framework teardown even if a interrupt/abort is received from Jenkins?

Comment: If you are doing the test in `build` option of Jenkins then surely Teardown won't get executed when job is aborted. If you can add an exception in your framework to handle abort like situation and call Teardown in that exception then it will work.

Comment: It all run in pipeline. Test is one of the stages. Do you know how to make the teardown work in case of sigterm received ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do in Teardown, you may not be able to call Teardown explicitly when sigterm is received but you can add a Teardown steps when sigterm is received. I too ran into this same problem once and I needed only to deinit the device under test. So I added a deinit function which was called when a sigterm was received

Comment: Any chance you can share your code? My problem is in short: I'm using external equipment and some locking mechanism that release all used equipment after test finished (during the teardown). If test was aborted and teardown wasn't executed all my equipment remain "reversed/locked"

Comment: I think it will be better if you can create the post-build action depending on job status to run the teardown. When you abort the build, it's like force close of everything without any hearsay. So robot framework wouldn't be able to run it .

Comment: @ashtav you're right, but I wanted to keep the execution logic within the same robotframework suite...

Comment: @user2988257 please look to this Git Hub issue , there are few suggestions which might help https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2451

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that jenkins controls your robotframework's lifecyle and test execution, and not the opposit.
A solution could be to add a post action in your pipeline (or jenkinsfile) [Post action documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#:%7E:text=post%20can%20support%20any%20of,of%20the%20Pipeline%20or%20stage.) that should call tests including only your teardowns.
After that inside the post action you have to add the scripts that could run your teardown .
For optimization you could add a flag to indicate whether teardown have been run in the main stage or not, or even better you can put the teardown only one time as a post action.
You can manage test reports via rebot merge command.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's not a solution, it will totally affect the robotframework reports and the flow.

Comment: You might disagree but that's the only way to solve the issue.While I don't agree with your comment here are my concerns (since I worked with Jenkinsfiles and pipelines for ~ 4 years and there were also DevOps experts in the team) : 1) If the job has been aborted by Jenkins for whatever reason there is no way to get complete test reports (in best case you could get previous reports if they were run in separate stages + you might end up with a corrupted XML file for test being run while the abort happened). 2) The op didn't mention that they don't have the ability to change the flow

Comment: There is no magic in software development. It is just impossible to interrupt the execution and then try to get complete report/log. The solution I suggessted has the less comlexity for implementation and it also gurantees that the teardown (which is important for the op) are going to be run (unless the whole jenskins server is down). So in summary I disagree with your downvote, it isn't appropriate and your arguments aren't 100 % valid .

Comment: By the way @Sreevathsabr has also mentioned about post-build action. Because in fact, you have to understand that this is the only choice you have in this case (using your question as a requirement).

Comment: Appreciate your response and respect your solid experience, thus I'll remove the downvote (actually I cannot do that cause the vote is locked and cannot be removed until the answer is changed, sorry)